# What is the conceptual difference between posterior and likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, posterior, intuition, definition

I have trouble discerning conceptually between these two notions. I am aware of their formal relations, proprieties and what not, but I just can't wrap my head around what they "mean", if that even makes sense. I have checked some answers, such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208941/what-is-the-difference-and-relationship-between-posterior-distribution-function), but I think none of these addresses my problem.

So, given some data $\mathcal{D}$ and parameters $\theta$,

$$
p(\theta|\mathcal{D})=\frac{p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(\mathcal{D})}
$$

I have learned that the posterior is "the probability of $\theta$ being the statistical parameter underlying $\mathcal{D}$". And the likelihood is "the likelihood of $\theta$ having generated $\mathcal{D}$". In my head, these two notions are exactly the same. So how can I distinguish them?

Comment: I would just say it like the conditional formula says it: the posterior is the probability of getting $\theta$ given some data $D$, the likelihood is the probability of getting $D$ if the parameter $\theta$ is true.

Comment: I don't think that thinking of $P(D|\theta)$, as you have, "the likelihood of $\theta$ having generated D" is a useful way of thinking about it. I think of it as "if we knew that $\theta$ took a particular value, what would the probability of observing the data we have be?"

That is different to "given the data we have, what do we think the true value of $\theta$ is?"

Comment: @gazza89 this is actually how I thought of this before getting into ML and bayesian probability. I used to think of p(x|y) as simply conditional probabilities, but now I hear that the likelihood is not a p.d.f. and this kinda confuses me. If it's just the probability of D given $\theta$, then why is it not a pdf?

Comment: The likelihood is a pdf, it's just normalised w.r.t  all possible data outcomes, and the posterior is a pdf, but it's normalised w.r.t all possible parameter values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to have a posterior distribution for $\theta$, $\theta$ must be (modeled as) a random variable. For the likelihood function that is not necessary. So this is deeper than the comment (by @gazza89) saying

> The likelihood is a pdf, it's just normalised w.r.t all possible data
>   outcomes, and the posterior is a pdf, but it's normalised w.r.t all
>   possible parameter values

Even if the likelihood was (or could be normalized too, it is not always possible) to integrate to one, that is not enough to make it into a pdf (probability density function). A pdf must be the pdf *of some random variable* and if $\theta$ is not modeled as a random variable, then it cannot have a pdf, period.

So conceptually it is quite clear-cut:

- If $\theta$ is a random variable (probably in some Bayesian model) then it can have a posterior, and it can have a likelihood function. Even if those two functions should be numerically equal (as for instance if the prior is uniform), they are distict mathematical entities.
- If $\theta$ is not (modeled as) a random variable the problem does not arise, only the likelihood function can be defined.

You say

> And the likelihood is "the likelihood of θ having generated D"

but that is not a good way of thinking about it. Likelihood tells you the probability (under the model ...) of *the data* *if data was generated according to that value of $\theta$*. There is **no "probability of $\theta$" involved**. To get that you need some extra assumptions, a Bayesian probability model.

To understand likelihood better see all the answers to [Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) in layman terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/112480#112480).

Answer (score 2):

To put simply, likelihood is "the likelihood of $\theta$ having generated $\mathcal{D}$" and posterior is essentially "the likelihood of $\theta$ having generated $\mathcal{D}$" **further multiplied** by the prior distribution of $\theta$.

If the prior distribution is flat (or non-informative), likelihood is exactly the same as posterior.

Comment: This is a good intuition but it is incomplete because the posterior distribution is normalized (so that it is a distribution over theta) while the likelihood is not. What you say could hold for the non-normalized posterior density, if you define it appropriately.